# RecyclerView lazy loading

Tags: android-viewholder

I'm doing lazy loading on a RecyclerView adapter. First I fetch the image metadata (if it has any) and then let Picasso download the actual image.

```
public class PostHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements Callback<Photo>{
    private PostImageView cover;
    private TextView content;
    private long id;

    public PostHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.itemView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content);
        cover = (PostImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
    }

    public void setPost(final Post post, int i){
        cover.unsetImage();
        this.id = post.getPhotoId();
        itemView.setTag(i);
        content.setText(post.getMessage());

        if("photo".equals(post.getType()) || "video".equals(post.getType()) && id != 0L){
            cache.get(id, this);
        }else{
            cover.setUrl(post.getImageUrl());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void result(Photo result) {
        if(result != null && result.getId() == PostHolder.this.id){
            cover.setPhoto(result);
        }
    }
}
```

`cache.get()` loads my metadata from the cache, the result is returned with `result()`.`setPost()` gets called in `onBindViewHolder()`. Now I'm getting everyone's favorite viewholder issue - my `ImageView` displays a different image before switching to the correct one. I know that Picasso correctly handles this and I have a check for my own loading where i compare the holder's id to the metadata id. I've spent a few hours on this already. Internet, you are my only hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed now, though I'm not exactly sure why. I believe it's

```
Picasso
    .with(getContext())
    .cancelRequest(this);
```

inside `unsetImage()` because of the double request needed to load it.

What I think happens:

1. `Picasso` is still loading the previous image.
2. A call for the current image metadata is dispatched.
3. `Picasso` loads the preVious image. Since `Picasso` doesn't know about the metadata, it's not automatically canceled.
4. The metadata get's loaded, and `Picasso` starts loading the current image.