# Lazy loading not working for RecyclerView using Volley

Tags: android, lazy-loading, android-volley, android-recyclerview

Am able to parse `json` (text+image) feed and display them in a grid manner inside `RecyclerView`. As mentioned in the question , am using `Volley` library. 
I have my `Volley Singleton` , `LruBitmapCache` as described in [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/).

Everything works fine except the lazy loading part i.e the views are visible only after loading all the text as well as images. Of course the ideal way is to load texts first without waiting for the images to get downloaded , which i am not able to achieve right now.

`onBindViewHolder` of my `RecyclerView Adapter`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final FeedItemBangCake item = feedItems.get(position);
    viewHolder.name.setText(item.getName());
    viewHolder.price.setText("Rs." + String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));
    viewHolder.prodId.setText(String.valueOf(item.getUniProdId()));
    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


    // Feed image
    if (item.getImge() != null) {


        imageLoader.get(item.getImge(), new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {
                viewHolder.feedImageView.setImageUrl(imageContainer.getRequestUrl(), imageLoader);
                viewHolder.feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        });


    } else {
        viewHolder.feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

`getJsonData()` - the method inside a fragment responsible for making volley request

```
 private void getJsonData(String URL_FEED_DATA) {

    // first check for cached request
    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED_DATA);
    if (entry != null) {
        // fetch the data from cache
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            try {
                parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));                    
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        // making fresh volley request and getting json
        JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_FEED_DATA, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                if (response != null) {
                    parseJsonFeed(response);                        
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // Adding request to volley request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);

    }
```

`parseJsonFeed()` is obviously the method which is parsing json data.

**What i tried till now :**

I tried to load the images in a separate thread by wrapping the image loading part of adapter inside `run()` but of no use.

```
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        });
```

Will it be a good idea to make a separate volley request for images while texts are getting loaded with another request?

Note : The tutorial which i mentioned , deals with lazy loading too. I followed the exact procedure as the tutorial did , still lazy loading in my case not working.

Comment: check this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29255667/5955836)